# Updating Redux State after adding an item to the DB

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am still quite a newb with this. I'm trying to build a small Full-Stack app for keeping track of hours in projects.

I have a Ruby on Rails API with Postgresql database and a React front with Redux, Redux-React and Redux-thunk for state-management. All the CRUD-functionalities work fine between the front and back-end, but i just cant get the Redux state to update after any operation.

My initial state

```
{data: Array(2), included: Array(6)}
    data: Array(7)
      0:
        attributes: {done: false, date: "2021-01-08", name: "Test3", customer: "Test3", sum_hours: 0}
        id: "69"
        relationships: {tasks: {…}}
        type: "project"
        __proto__: Object
      1: {id: "70", type: "project", attributes: {…}, relationships: {…}}
      2: {id: "71", type: "project", attributes: {…}, relationships: {…}}
      3: {id: "72", type: "project", attributes: {…}, relationships: {…}}
      4: {id: "73", type: "project", attributes: {…}, relationships: {…}}
      5: {id: "1", type: "project", attributes: {…}, relationships: {…}}
      6: {id: "5", type: "project", attributes: {…}, relationships: {…}}
length: 7
__proto__: Array(0)
included: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
__proto__: Object
```

This is coming to my reducer from actions after succesful POST to db

```
{type: "ADD_NEW", data: {…}}
  data:
    attributes: {done: false, date: "2021-01-08", name: "Testi1", customer: "Testi1", sum_hours: 0}
    id: "74"
    relationships: {tasks: {…}}
    type: "project"
    __proto__: Object
    type: "ADD_NEW"
    __proto__: Object
```

My Reducer

```
const ProjectReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_NEW':             
            return Object.assign({}, state.data,
                {
                    attributes: action.attributes,
                    id: action.id,
                    relationships: action.relationships
                })        
        case 'DEL_PRO':             
            return state.data.filter(st => st.id != action.id)
        case 'INIT_PROJECTS':
            return action       
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default ProjectReducer
```

I have tried many things on my reducers ADD_NEW, one you see now is just the latest,
cant get anything to update the state. Even the DEL_PRO wont work, when i dispatch my delete
on the app it just loses the state completely. All help is much appreciated!

Comment: A reducer should return a COMPLETE new state or the COMPLETE original state each return. For DEL_PRO you appear to be returning only an array of data and not the complete state, try `return {...state, data: state.data.filter(st => st.id != action.id)};`. This appears to be the same issue for ADD_NEW, but this one is more complex. You will need to return a COMPLETE state creating a new root object (either through `Object.assign` or using the spread operator) and the data array to ensure the references are updated. You will need to find and update the correct index in the array before returning.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i realized my state was unnecessarily too complex, so i ended up modifying my initial state to get rid of too many nested levels. Works now like a charm.

Comment: You might want to take a look at an immutability library to help with updating your state. They provide differing tools / levels of help. Some examples are [Immutability Helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) mentioned by the react docs which provides a new syntax for updating immutables and [Immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction) which allows for the use of normal JavaScript mutations through its draft then commit setup. Each of these has a differing overhead that will reduce performance, but in most normal cases the difference is not perceivable.

Answer (score 0):

I think state.data is an array so you should do:

```
case 'ADD_NEW': 
  return {
    ...state,
    data: state.data.concat({
      attributes: action.attributes,
      id: action.id,
      relationships: action.relationships,
    }),
  }
```

Comment: Didn't work with that either. I realized that my state was unnecessarily too complex so i ended up modifying my initial state to get rid of too many nested levels. Works now like a charm. Thanks for your help tho!